# Get the disconnected user from socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets

I'm writing a live chat system in Node.js. Where user connects with server I'm creating unique hash key [one time creation] and join him in new chat room. I want to show whether the user online or not. while user disconnects the socket I could not get the user's chat room so that I couldn't find whether the user Online or not. Pls suggest is there any better way to do that.

**Server.js**

```
socket.on('newUser',function (user) {
    chat.createChatRoom(con, user.email, user.phone, function (res,user_id,chatToken) {
        chatToken="TOK"+chatToken; //Here we using TOK for some identical purposes
        chatRoom(socket,chatToken,1);
        io.sockets.in(chatToken).emit('newUser', {chatToken:chatToken,user_id:user_id,response:res,rooms:io.sockets.adapter.rooms});
        io.emit('userConnects',chatToken);
        console.log(JSON.stringify(io.sockets.adapter.rooms));

    });
});
```

**Create Chat Room Function :**

```
var createChatRoom = function (con, email, phone,callback) {
var chatToken = require('crypto').createHash('md5').update(email).digest("hex");
con.query("SELECT * FROM USER WHERE `email`='" + email + "'", function (error, result) {
    if (error) throw error;
    if (result.length == 0) {
        con.query("INSERT INTO user(email,chat_token,phone) VALUES('" + email + "','" + chatToken + "','" + phone + "')", function (error1, result1) {
            return callback(1,result1.insertId,chatToken);
        });
    } else {
        return callback(0,result[0].user_id,chatToken);
    }
});
};
```

While user disconnects I want to get **chatToken**. But I can get socket id only.

Answer (score 1):

You need to also store socket.id in a new column for a new User when creating a new chat user. Then when the user disconnects you can search the user by socket.id.

```
chat.createChatRoom(con, socket.id, user.email, user.phone, function (res,user_id,chatToken) {...})
```

Actually, You don't even need to create a chat token yourself if the only purpose is to identify a socket connection. Because socket.id is random, unguessable, unique identifier for each socket connection.

Comment: I want a unique and permanent chatToken so that I can trigger new message particularly. The socket id is random so that I could find which user is disconnected.

Comment: @SarathKumar Each room can have multiple sockets(users) connected so better idea would be to persist users belonging to the chat room in another table. So you can add and remove users(with the socket.id to identify room members) when they join or disconnect. Rooms do not disconnect, users do. And, you can broadcast to all the members of the room with the chatToken.

Comment: But here I'm creating separate chat room for each client. To send private messages.

Comment: Then have both chatToken and socket.id in the database. but, you need to update socket.id in database everytime the use joins and remove it when the user disconnects.

Comment: You mean, I have to update the socket.id to chatToken. So that I can get which user is disconnects.

Comment: You can have both chatToken and socket.id. Create new column socket_id in the table and store socket.id, when the user joins, and remove it when the user disconnects. Not having socket_id in the database row will mean the user is offline.

Comment: If the user open another tab that will cause problem. Bcoz it'll create new socket.id. So previous tab become inactive. that's the reason I created permanent chatToken. Hope u get.

Comment: You need to then create a new table socket_sessions where you store all the socket_ids a chatToken is related with. For each socket connection, you create a new row. When a socket disconnects you remove it from the table. When there are no socket_ids at all in the table for the chatToken then that will mean the user is offline altogether.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to detect if the user is disconnected is would be to first set the username in socket session

```
socket.on('newUser',function (username) {
            // we store the username in the socket session for this client
            socket.username = username;
});
```

and when the user disconnects find that on the disconnect event

```
socket.on('disconnect', function () {
    var connectionMessage = socket.username + " Disconnected from Socket " + socket.id;
    console.log(connectionMessage);
  });
```